# how to create 3D shape of layout or Or button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, 3d, android-button

In android XML how can create 3d layout or 3d button shape  please help me
I have already created a 2d layout[image: this is my 2d design]
I want to add 3D shape. android:elevation and android:translationZ is not working because the background is already black and I want to add something like this [image: see this 3d shape]

Comment: It is just a shadow , wrap your button in cardview with corner radius and elevation ,

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>        
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#0905FB"
                    android:startColor="#9796FD"
                    android:angle="270" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="3dp"
                    android:color="#65655B" />
                <corners
                    android:radius="3dp" />  
                <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
   </selector>
```

This will give the gradient and shape You can change gradient angle, color and button radius as per your requirement. Keep button in cardview and give elevation for 3d like view.

Answer (score 1):

- create xml file in drawable folder with Root Element "layer-list" and copy this code inside of "layer-list" tag :)

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

        <gradient android:startColor="#0094a8"
            android:endColor="#0094a8"
            android:centerColor="#06BDD8"
          />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:height="20dp"
    android:top="8dp"
    android:end="25dp"
    android:start="25dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#20ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

This code is very similar to your request

Comment: hi, can we create a ticket view layout? , I have tried your custom shape answer 
but it's not  working I think we can't change the card view background anyway can we 
do this